# Как разбить число?

Tags: java

Есть число формата DDDDDRRRPC. Нужно отделить C, P, RRR, DDDDDD. Как это можно реализовать? В Java только учусь ещё, вроде как можно это сделать с помощью %, но у самого не получилось

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если позиции символов в числе известны то проще всего использовать встроенный функционал работы со строками. Преобразуйте число в строку, откусите нужную часть, преобразуйте обратно.

```
String numbStr = String.valueOf(numberCPRD);  //переводим чисто в текстовый вид
int numberC = Integer.parseInt(numbStr.substring(9)); //C
int numberP = Integer.parseInt(numbStr.substring(8, 9)); //P
int numberR = Integer.parseInt(numbStr.substring(5, 8)); //RRR
int numberD = Integer.parseInt(numbStr.substring(0, 5)); //DDDDDD
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("DDDDDRRRPC".split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)")));
```